# Issue updating labview waveform chart

Tags: labview

I have a labview program where I am collecting data at 2 Hz. I have 8 channels of data I need to plot on a waveform chart. However, due to the program needing to be ran for long periods of time, I run into issues with memory and storing all the data on the chart. I would like to have it be a user input update frequency, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried passing the data in through a loop, but it would never execute.

To paint a clearer picture, I want to plot every other data point or further in between. I don't need all the data points on the plot.

Comment: Posting a VI snippet of what you've tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the master-slave code setup and have an event triggered update.  If you need to you can create a global var file to store your data, then when you trigger the update it will read it from that.

I tend to always separate the UI in labview into its' own thread this way and it works well for what you're describing.

[image]